# Is there google public transportation routine API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have longitude and latitude of objects and want to know if the position of object is near a bus routine, tram routine or train railway.

I saw the routine(train/bus/car/foot etc) functionality on google map, is there any programming API to that ?

Answer (score 0):

The Google [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/) might meet your needs.

Comment: In that case, I don't believe there is an API that meets your exact needs.